# How to I get the desired part from the string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this string, I want to get the part after the date. The part till date always remains the same. I would have hoped to get the index of date but it changes always hence I can't use it.

```
var str = "c:\ somefolder\ download\ 2019-14-11 merchandise of today"

char[] spearator = {" "};

var _split = str.Split(spearator);
```

Here I have all the words broken down according to spaces.
How do I get the 'merchandise of today'?

Comment: You can try str = str .Substring(str .IndexOf(' ') + 1);  It will give output as you needed

Comment: I completely agree with @Mdyahiya. It would be really great if you search and read before posting a question. I am deleting my answer to encourage OP to do some research.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, Thank you. The reason i pointed because, I have taken such help in my initial years and i didnt improve my skills until i started to do search and try myself.

Comment: Thanks, guys, please read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the date does not change, you could do the following:

```
var path = @"C:\Example\Download\2019-14-11 Merchandise Of Today";
var merchandise = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\')).Trim();
```

**OR**

```
var merchandiseWithoutDate = path.Substring(path.IndexOf(' ').Trim();
```

That will output the date and merchandise of today, if you change the character to a space you will also retrieve that.

What `Substring` is basically allows you to control an index to begin and end, which allows you to mitigate the text received.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following codes, use the regular expression

```
            var str = @"c:\ somefolder\ download\ 2019-14-11 merchandise of today";

            var reg = new Regex(@".+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}");

            var result = reg.Replace(str, string.Empty).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

//Thanks guys!

//This is what I did before I saw the two answers. I know it is messy a lot and now I am //gonna try the substring method but this was a temporary fix for me. Thanks again!

```
var str = "c:\ somefolder\ download\ 2019-14-11 merchandise of today"

char[] spearator = {" "};

var _split = str.Split(spearator);

int len = _split.lenght-1;

for(i=0; i<_split.lenght; i++)
{
var getStr = _split[i]
Match search = regex.match(getStr, "my regex patern for date");

if (search.success)
{
var converted  = search.tostring();
int index = Array.IndexOf(_split, converted)
index++;
string temp = "";
while(index<=len_)
{
string temp = temp+ " "+_split[index];
index++;
}
console.writeline("String is {0}", temp);
}
}
```